# At shutdown my PC has begun to display "(Waiting for) Form1"

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

There is this program that is preventing my PC from shutting down

[image: (Waiting for) Form1]

I have no idea what it is, it started two days ago.

I have googled it and no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a poorly written (e.g. Visual Basic) program that utilizes default names for window to me. Check what you are running with process explorer/resource explorer. Sometimes trojan/viruses/etc could be so poorly written that it has a name like this with poorly implemented handler for shutdown (close).

Comment: Yup it was just a badly written program http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/display-ram-and-cpu-usage-on-windows-7-taskbar/

Answer (score 1):

That’s because `Form1` is not the name of the program, but rather a the main ‘control/window’ of a program written in Delphi or VisualBasic.

What you want to try is to cancel the shutdown, then find out what the program is.

Get a tool like [WinSpy++](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy) and run it in administrator mode. Click the More button, then for each process, double-click it and look for which one contains Form1. (Too bad I have not published my WindowManipulation tool; it would have made this easier.) `:-(`

When you’ve located the process, click on Form1 and then click the down-arrow next to the Handle field to see the window to determine if it is something you know about. Click the Process tab to find where it is located.

Once you have this information, you/we can determine what it is and what to do about it.